# Customizing vim-terraform indentation

Tags: vim, terraform, indentation, auto-indent

### Overview

I just downloaded **vim-terraform** from https://github.com/hashivim/vim-terraform
And this plug-in let my terraform-file be indented well.

if i write terraform code i can see auto-indented file in *.tf like below code

```
ami                    = data.aws_ami.ubuntu16.id
subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet.lucent_public.id
availability_zone      = var.azn
vpc_security_group_ids = ...
```

### Problem

But i just want to make my code look like below

```
ami = data.aws_ami.ubuntu16.id
subnet_id = data.aws_subnet.lucent_public.id
availability_zone = var.azn
vpc_security_group_ids = ...
```

**with no auto-indentation near '=' sign. 
Is it possible with vim-terraform ?**

Comment: The plugin doesn't allow you to customise that so you'd need to fork it and remove the indent stuff. But Terraform ships with an opinionated formatter (`terraform fmt`) like Go does and as such the canonical way to write Terraform files is to indent like the formatter will do so. If you did want to do this you'd probably want to make sure the `terraform fmt` on save hook is disabled too as this will also indent your code.